# How to remove br while extracting contents from database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to develop the dynamic site using PHP and obsolete `mysql_query`.

I need to extract limited contents from my database so I've used `substr` and this content is placed at the index page. But while the user edits the page, the content is formatted, sometimes the font size is too large, sometimes the content has lots of `<br>`. It destroys the look of my website.  I'm troubled by unnecessary `<br>` and want to remove it and also want to ignore the formatted font size in the index page.

My code goes like this:

```
 <?php
 $sql = "SELECT contents FROM table";
 $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
     $contents = $row['contents'];
     echo substr($fld_page_details, 0,125); 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: try using regex to do a filter of your contents. Using replace,or substr it self will be trouble you too.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php
 $sql = "SELECT contents FROM table";
 $result = mysql_query($sql)  or die(mysql_error());
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $contents = $row['contents'];
 echo str_replace('<br>', '', $contents); 
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Yes, it works but how do I fix with 
     echo substr($contents, 0,125);
I need to display only 125 characters.

Comment: substr() function will work only for the exact line, If <br> tag exist multiple time in your contents then?? than subtr() will not work. If you used str_replace() this will remove all br tags from contents.

Comment: I understand it but I need to use substr also and remove br. Is there any other way??

Comment: if you compel to use the substr then e.g three time br exist in your content you need to call three time substr with exact string points of start and end. this is only with substr but if you can apply str_replace than it too good.

Comment: I tried to use like this but it didn't work.
echo str_replace('<br>', '', $contents);     
echo substr($contents, 0,125); How to use it correctly?

Comment: make sure how the tag is displaying, try echo str_replace('<br>', '', $contents); echo str_replace('<br />', '', $contents); if still no success than try echo strip_tags($contents);

Comment: Can't you just do echo substr(str_replace('<br>', '', $contents), 0,125); or if you want to strip all html tags substr(strip_tags($contents), 0,125);?

Comment: Thank You @KarasQ for your guidance. It really solved my problem. But what if I need to remove some special characters like &æ #� etc.

Comment: Try: $string = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $String);

Comment: @Iffi  Since I'm just a beginner kindly tell me how to adjust the above code in echo substr(str_replace('<br>', '', $contents), 0,125);

Comment: @JKLYN the things you are asking actually are very basic one not only for PHP but for general programming. You should at least read one tutorial, book or manual for beginners to understand answers to your questions and the most basic things like assignation to a variable or function calls. This would take you maybe 30 minutes and you will be able to use all functions in PHP manual all the time. Now you are waiting 2 days for someone to answer your question and even if someone give you a solution you still will be asking the same question in future... beginners should learn basics first.